# zf2 Module (DoctrineModule) could not be initialized

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, composer-php

Hi i'm trying to install doctrine2 to zf2 via composer. 
I'm getting error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (DoctrineModule) could not be initialized.'`
I followed this steps https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule

my application.config looks like this:

```
return array(
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'Album',
    'User'
),
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'config_glob_paths'    => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ),
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
    ),
),
);
```

My composer.json:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master",
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "*",
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-profiler": "*"
},
```

All needed doctrine librarys are in vendor/doctrine directory. I guess it's something wrong with autoloading.
After composer update i get message:
`[ErrorException]
proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 267`
i can't tell wath it means, but maybe this will be helpfull.

Second thing is that on https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule there is section:
`Installation steps (without composer)` and point 3. `setup PSR-0 autoloading for namespace DoctrineORMModule` ...where can I setup this thing ?

Comment: My problem was the permissions I had in my module folder and files. (I'm in a Ubuntu PC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1063 and https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1346 this looks like a problem with the setup of PHP under your environment (which I assume is windows).

The modules weren't installed correctly and composer did not dump the autoloader correctly because it crashed during the installation process.

Try repeating the installation process in a different path and check that you're using the latest version of composer with `php composer.phar self-update`

Answer (score 4):

If some of vendor folders was created on another machine, this can lead to the error you got. So perform the following.

1. Try to remove `composer.lock` and `./vendor` folder.
2. Then `php composer.phar self-update`
3. Run `php composer.phar install` to re-install dependencies.